# Remove duplicates from dict of lists with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, group-by

I'm trying to extract dictionary from dataframe with no duplicates.

Here is the dataframe:

```
{'Country': {0: 'Japan', 1: 'China', 2: 'USA', 3: 'Russia', 4: 'Japan', 
5: 'Japan', 6: 'China'}, 'Port': {0: 'Yokohama', 1: 'Ningbo', 2: 
'Baltimore', 3: 'Moscow', 4: 'Tokyo', 5: 'Tokyo', 6: 'Shanghai'}}
```

I set the countries as keys and removed duplicates.Now I need to remove the duplicates from list

```
import pandas as pd
a ={'Country': {0: 'Japan', 1: 'China', 2: 'USA', 3: 'Russia', 4: 'Japan', 
5: 'Japan', 6: 'China'}, 'Port': {0: 'Yokohama', 1: 'Ningbo', 2: 
'Baltimore', 3: 'Moscow', 4: 'Tokyo', 5: 'Tokyo', 6: 'Shanghai'}}

a_dict=a.groupby(['Country'])['Port'].apply(list).to_dict()
print(a_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'China': ['Ningbo', 'Shanghai'], 'Japan': ['Yokohama', 'Tokyo', 
'Tokyo'], 'Russia': ['Moscow'], 'USA': ['Baltimore']}
```

Expected output:

```
{'China': ['Ningbo', 'Shanghai'], 'Japan': ['Yokohama', 'Tokyo'], 
'Russia': ['Moscow'], 'USA': ['Baltimore']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `GroupBy.apply` with `set`

```
df.groupby('Country')['Port'].apply(set).map(list).to_dict()
```

If you don't care that your output is a dict of lists or dict of sets, this will simplify to

```
df.groupby('Country')['Port'].apply(set).to_dict()
```

---

#### `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
for c, p in zip(df['Country'], df['Port']):
    d[c].add(p)

{k: list(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) along with your code:

```
d = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['Country'])['Port'].apply(list).to_dict()

print(d)
{'China': ['Ningbo', 'Shanghai'], 'Japan': ['Yokohama', 'Tokyo'], 
 'Russia': ['Moscow'], 'USA': ['Baltimore']}
```